# Return a Boolean if a string consists of a hex character

Tags: python, escaping, hex

I want to know if a string is using an escape character to represent a hex character. Something that works in the same style as `string.isalnum()`:

```
"\x01".ishex()
```

returns `True`

and

```
"^".ishex()
```

returns `False`.

Does such a function exist?

If not, is there anything that returns `True` if it only contains escape characters?

Comment: You can check to see if something is a hex character with the boolean expression `ch in '0123456789abcdefABCDEF'`. To check a whole string `s`, just use `all(ch in '0123456789abcdefABCDEF' for ch in s)`. `"\x01"` is not a hex character BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"\x01"` does not actually contain an escape character. It is just a string where the first character is the byte with value 1. This is due to the fact that -- at least prior to python 3 -- python uses strings to represent byte arrays.

Try this in a REPL:

```
>>> "\x30" == "0"
True
>>>
```

This is due to the fact that the character `0` is represented as a byte with value 30.

Now, if you *really really* want to do this. You can use trevor's hack or you can just check if the string has any non-printable characters which end up being represented as hex sequences.

```
import string

def is_hex(a):
    printable = set(string.printable) - set("\x0b\x0c")
    return any(c not in printable for c in a)
```

Usage:

```
>>> is_hex("\x01")
True
>>> is_hex("^")
False
>>>
```

Comment: I think your `is_hex` function is the best way to go. One suggestion though is that you don't need square brackets inside of `any`. It will happily take values from a generator expression, and in fact, it will stop early if it gets a true result.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit it. I'm just too used to using list comprehensions instead of generator expressions. Back when I started using python they weren't there and I never got used to using them. I love how you can learn things even when answering questions on SO

Comment: `string.printable` contains `\t\n\r\x0b\x0c`, though.  The last two, at least, seem like they should cause `is_hex` to return `True`.

Comment: Good point, I didn't catch that. Simple fix though in incoming edit(and can be generalised to any other characters we wish to consider non-printable like `\t`,`\r` etc...

Comment: Oh wow, somebody accepted my answer 5 years after the fact... O_O

Answer (score 1):

ASCII defines "[printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)" as those between 0x20 to 0x7E so you can just check the character's code point.

```
def is_printable(c):
  return ord(c) >= 0x20 and ord(c) <= 0x7E
```

You could also check the length of the representation though its kind of a hack:

```
def is_hex(s):
  return len(repr(s)) > len(s) + 2

>>> is_hex("\x01")
True
>>> is_hex("^")
False
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to do this automatically. Hex-encoding (in any language) is 'encoding' using a limited set of ASCII code-set characters to represent some other character/s in a different range. Hex can be represented in a string several ways ("OA" could be interpreted as hex or some escaped-format for the hex-based numeric value). Yes, a function could be be written based on some of these standard forms but it would not be 100% reliable as the best it could return is that said String (which is really just an array of characters) is definitely NOT or 'might be' hex.